# Getting wrong printf output for floats

Tags: c

In the following:

```
float n1= 3.0;
double n2 = 3.0;
long n3 = 2000000000L;
long n4 = 1234567890L;
printf("%f %Lf %ld %ld\n", n1, n2, n3, n4);
```

> 3.000000 1.200000 2000000000 1234567890

Why is `1.2` printed for the second value and not `3.0`? I suppose maybe I'm screwing up the `float` prints -- with `float`, `double`, and `long double`, or what's the reason why the above prints an incorrect result? Is this the correct way to print all decimal-types?

```
float n1= 3.0F;
double n2 = 3.0;
long double n3 = 3.0L;
printf("%f %f %Lf\n", n1, n2, n3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Becaue `%Lf` isn't the specifier for `double`, it's the specifier for `long double`. `float` promotes to `double` automatically; hence `%f` covers both `float` and `double`. But `long double` needs its own.

You kinda got lucky here. On some platforms, the rest of the arguments would be misaligned.

Comment: are all non-qualified decimal literals parsed as `double` ? For example, if I enter in 2.0, would that be `double` unless doing `2.0L` (long) or `2.0F` (float) ?

Comment: @carl.hiass: The rule in play is you passed a `float` as an argument to a variadic function. There are no vardiac floats. 2.0 would be a float in a context that allowed it to be.

Comment: ok, but when I enter a decimal literal in VS Code it displays it as a `double` unless I qualify it. For example: https://gyazo.com/e78a218fdcd29c240019b8ff4038e11a

Comment: @carl.hiass: A difference that makes no difference. On all modern platforms, all floating point arithmetic is done by casting all arguments to long double, performing the calculation, and casting them back.

Comment: @Joshua, pretty sure that not all modern platforms cast to long double, given that some do have higher precision long doubles than doubles, and the cost of those higher precision operations can be substantially higher than doubles, in terms of power consumption, memory/registers and execution time. Think IoT. Your statement is likely true for most PC's and Servers.

Comment: @jwdonahue: I've seen some for which long double was just double if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Joshua, well that too, but there are systems that don't even have floating point coprocessors or built-in operations, so when you are forced to do some float-ops, you have to rely on software implementations, where gratuitous casting to higher precision would be a firing offense.